# jnr-ffi: Is there a generation tool from header files to java code

Tags: java, ffi, jnr

Is there a tool that generates java code from header files for the project [jnr-ffi](https://github.com/jnr/jnr-ffi). I what to offer an API for a C-project with approx. 1200 functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such tool. But it's a reason to develop it.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is thinking about integrating a similar thing into the JVM ([Project Panama](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama)). And they talk about a generator tool, see here [Devoxx Belgium 2016: Java Language and Platform Futures: A Sneak Peek by Brian Goetz](https://youtu.be/oGll155-vuQ?t=3028). But this may take a while.

Comment: https://github.com/openjdk/panama-foreign/blob/foreign-jextract/doc/panama_jextract.md

Comment: jdk22: https://github.com/openjdk/jextract/tree/jdk22

Comment: Java22 is GA: https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/jdk-dev/2024-March/008827.html